# How do I increase buffer size for sending data through websocket in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I'm using a Websocket client in .NET (*System.Net.WebSockets*).
I'm trying to send data through Websocket that is bigger than the default buffer size (*65536*)

I found a method `SetBuffer` in the `ClientWebSocketOptions`

```
var clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
clientWebSocket.Options.SetBuffer(200000,200000);
```

But it doesn't work, it throwns an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

How can I **increase the buffer size** for this .NET library?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: A Websocket is a stream.  Why do you need to specify the length?  You can just send the data.  A Websocket is HTML over TCP.  A HTML has to be properly structured so every open tag has a close tag.  The receiving end of the websocket reads an entire HTML and expects a closing tag before processing the stream.

Comment: I solved the issue basically increasing the max frame buffer size on the websocket server side